# Prove $\sigma_g(x) \in Aut(R(x)/R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $R$ be a field and let $R(x)$ be the field of rational functions in $x$ whose coefficients are in $R$.

Let $g =
 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array} \right) \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and define $\sigma_g(x)$ so that

- $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma_g(r)=r  \space\space\space (\sigma_g=Id_R)$
- $\sigma_g(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$

can I conclude  $\sigma_g(x) \in Aut(R(x)/R)$?

the opposite direction is clear to me and is detailed in [**this post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/automorphism-of-the-field-of-rational-functions).

any help would be appreciated =]

Answer (score 1):

It's important that $(a,b)$ is not a constant multiple of $(c,d)$ so that $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ isn't a constant. The equivalent condition of course is that $\det(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})\ne0$.

Since $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is algebraic over $R\iff x$ is algebraic over $R$, we know $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is transcendental.

So there is an isomorphism $R(x)\to R(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d})$. Now think of this as a map $\sigma_g:R(x)\to R(x)$.

Since $\sigma_g$ has an inverse $\sigma_{g^{-1}}$ it is a field automorphism.