# Does $\mathbb{R}(X)$ have an automorphism of order 7?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, real-numbers, rational-functions, automorphism-group

The question comes from a 2020 home exam of an undergraduate course in field theory and Galois theory and is as follows:

> Let $\mathbb{R}(X)$ be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> > There is an automorphism $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{R}(X))$ such that the order of $\sigma$ is 7.

Some of the ideas, while trying to attack this question, were with
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/automorphism-of-the-field-of-rational-functions). But, after discovering that an automorphism of a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't necessarily preserve it (although [an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map)), I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

After more research online, I was surprised to find little to no information about similar questions.

I will greatly appreciate any information relevant to this question. Also, an interesting follow-up question:

- What is the automorphism group, $Aut(\mathbb{R}(X))$? What are the orders of automorphisms $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{R}(X))$?

Comment: The answer is PSO

Comment: @reuns what is PSO:  Portland Symphony Orchestra, Pakistan State Oil, Public Service Company of Oklahoma,...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an arbitrary field $K$, the field automorphisms of $K(x)$ *that fix* $K$ pointwise are the linear fractional substitutions: $f(x) \mapsto f((ax+b)/(cx+d))$ for all $f \in K(x)$, where $a, b, c, d \in K$ and $ad - bc \not= 0$. This is just a substitution map replacing $x$ with $(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ in all rational functions.
Such substitutions are determined by the matrix $(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})$ up to nonzero scaling, so the automorphisms of $K(x)$ fixing the elements of $K$ are isomorphic to the group ${\rm PGL}_2(K) = {\rm GL}_2(K)/K^\times$.  We express this as: ${\rm Aut}(K(x)/K) \cong {\rm PGL}_2(K)$.  This is related to Lüroth's Theorem, which says every field between $K$ and $K(x)$ is $K(f(x))$ for some rational function $f(x)$ in $K(x)$.

For some $K$ the field automorphisms of $K(x)$ don't all fix the elements of $K$, but when $K = \mathbf R$ it *is* true: every field automophism of $\mathbf R(x)$ fixes the elements of $\mathbf R$. See Theorem 5.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/autRandQp.pdf). So ${\rm Aut}(\mathbf R(x)) = {\rm Aut}(\mathbf R(x)/\mathbf R)$. Therefore your question amounts to asking when an element of ${\rm PGL}_2(\mathbf R)$ has order $7$.

By the way, it is not important to know first whether or not all field automorphisms of $\mathbf R(x)$ fix the constants because you could at least *start* by focusing on such automorphisms and see if you can find one like that with order $7$. If you find one, great!  Only if you suspect there isn't one would it become important to know that automorphisms of $\mathbf R(x)$ fix the elements of $\mathbf R$. But also, to be honest, I suspect nearly anyone who asks about field automorphisms of a rational function field only cares about those that actually fix the constants, and the failure to specify in the problem that "automorphism" means "automorphism fixing $\mathbf R$" might have just been an oversight.

Comment: The question comes from a 2020 home exam of an undergraduate course in Field Theory and Galois theory, I added the relevant information to the question.

Comment: In that case I am *certain* that the writer of that problem simply forgot to include the condition that the field automorphisms were meant to be only those fixing $\mathbf R$. The fact that the automorphisms of $\mathbf R(x)$ can be proved to fix each element of $\mathbf R$ seems like too subtle a point to expect students to be aware of.

Comment: At what university was that 2020 course being taught?

Comment: BTW if anyone's wondering, the answer was to use the rotation matrix of $2\pi/7$.
I'm not sure what space exactly is rotating here but it's pretty cool.

Comment: That a matrix in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbf R)$ acting on $\mathbf R^2$ has the effect of rotating that plane by some angle doesn't mean that everywhere else that matrix acts has to involve some actual rotation too.